# How can I showing truncated text only on hover without change height of box list?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component

My script of vue component like this :

```
<template>
  ...
    <b-card-group deck v-for="row in formattedClubs">
        <b-card  v-for="club in row"
                img-src="http://placehold.it/130?text=No-image"
                img-alt="Img"
                img-top>
            <h4 class="card-title" 
                @mouseenter="club.truncate = false"
                @mouseleave="club.truncate = true">
                <template v-if="club.truncate">{{trucateText(club.description)}}</template>
                <template v-else>{{club.description}}</template>
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text">
                {{club.price}}
            </p>
            <p class="card-text">
                {{club.country}}
            </p>
            <div slot="footer">
                <b-btn variant="primary" block>Add</b-btn>
            </div>
        </b-card>
    </b-card-group>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      clubs: [
          {id:1, description:'chelsea is the best club in the world and chelsea has a great player', price:1000, country:'england'},
          {id:2, description:'liverpool has salah', price:900, country:'england'},
          {id:3, description:'mu fans', price:800, country:'england'},
          {id:4, description:'city has a great coach. Thas is guardiola', price:700, country:'england'},
          {id:5, description:'arsenal player', price:600, country:'england'},
          {id:6, description:'tottenham in london', price:500, country:'england'},
          {id:7, description:'juventus stadium', price:400, country:'italy'},
          {id:8, description:'madrid sell ronaldo', price:300, country:'spain'},
          {id:9, description:'barcelona in the spain', price:200, country:'spain'},
          {id:10, description:'psg buys neymar at a fantastic price', price:100, country:'france'}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
      formattedClubs() {
          return this.clubs.reduce((c, n, i) => {
              if (i % 4 === 0) c.push([]);
              c[c.length - 1].push(n);
              this.$set(n, 'truncate', true); 
              return c;
          }, []);
      }
  },
  methods: {
      trucateText (value) {
          const length = 30;
          return value.length <= length ? value : value.substring(0, length) + "...";
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

If the script executed, the view like this :

[image]

If I hover the description, the result like this :

[image]

It change height of box list

How can I solve this problem?

I want the view like this :

[image]

Comment: you can wrap your truncate text with a tooltip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can see that you're using [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/). Nice, so you can use [v-b-tooltip directive](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/directives/tooltip/) and let itself control the hover behavior. As you don't need to track it by yourself anymore for each club, you can remove that reative property from your computed property `formattedClubs`:

```
this.$set(n, 'truncate', true); // Remove this line.
```

Now, update your template to use the directive only if the truncation is needed:

```
<h4 class="card-title"
    v-if="club.description.length > 30"
    v-b-tooltip.hover.bottom
    :title="club.description">
  {{trucate(club.description)}}
</h4>
<h4 v-else>{{club.description}}</h4>
```

And, of course, you can now style it the way you want overriding the right Boostrap styles:

```
.tooltip.show {
  opacity: 1;
} 

.tooltip-inner {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.tooltip.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow, .tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow {
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
  top: 1px;
  width: 16px;
}

.tooltip.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow::before, .tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before, .tooltip.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow::after, .tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::after {
  bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow::after, .tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

.tooltip.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=bottom] .arrow::before, .tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before {
  border-color: rgba(187, 187, 187, 0);
    border-bottom-color: #bbb;
    border-width: 9px;
    margin-left: -9px;
}
```

Take a look at the [fully working sampe here](https://codepen.io/ErickPetru/pen/WaQYyg) if you want.

Comment: Maybe you can help me again. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651862/how-can-i-make-slider-in-the-card-deck-group-on-the-bootstrap-vue

Answer (score 1):

I would simply wrap your truncated text with a tooltip component. You can pass the full text into this component as a prop.

On hover you can show the tooltip by using `@mouseover` and remove it by using `@mouseleave`.

The tooltip itself can be a position absolute element with a `max-width`. I am not going to type all of this out, but this should get you started.