# How can I make slider in the card deck group on the bootstrap vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I make card deck group using this tutorial : https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/card/#card-deck-groups

My script like this :

```
<template>
  <div class="animated fadeIn">
    <b-card-group deck v-for="row in formattedClubs">
        <b-card  v-for="club in row"
                img-src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/450"
                img-alt="Img"
                img-top>
            <h4 class="card-title">
                {{club.description}}
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text">
                {{club.price}}
            </p>
            <p class="card-text">
                {{club.country}}
            </p>
            <div slot="footer">
                <b-btn variant="primary" block>Add</b-btn>
            </div>
        </b-card>
    </b-card-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      clubs: [
          {id:1, description:'chelsea is the best club in the world and chelsea has a great player', price:1000, country:'england'},
          {id:2, description:'liverpool has salah', price:900, country:'england'},
          {id:3, description:'mu fans', price:800, country:'england'},
          {id:4, description:'city has a great coach. Thas is guardiola', price:700, country:'england'},
          {id:5, description:'arsenal player', price:600, country:'england'},
          {id:6, description:'tottenham in london', price:500, country:'england'},
          {id:7, description:'juventus stadium', price:400, country:'italy'},
          {id:8, description:'madrid sell ronaldo', price:300, country:'spain'},
          {id:9, description:'barcelona in the spain', price:200, country:'spain'},
          {id:10, description:'psg buys neymar at a fantastic price', price:100, country:'france'}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
      formattedClubs() {
          return this.clubs.reduce((c, n, i) => {
              if (i % 4 === 0) c.push([]);
              c[c.length - 1].push(n);
              return c;
          }, []);
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to add slider. So I want the slider like this :

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

To achieve that result you have to use some `methods` , `computed` properties and styles, here a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8y42nwz838) and [demo](https://8y42nwz838.codesandbox.io/):

```
<template>
  <div class="animated fadeIn ">
    <b-card-group  deck >
        <b-card  v-for="(club,index) in currentPageClubs" :key="index"
                img-src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/300"
                img-alt="Img"
                img-top >
            <h4 class="card-title">
                {{club.description}}
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text">
                {{club.price}}
            </p>
            <p class="card-text">
                {{club.country}}
            </p>
            <div slot="footer">
                <b-btn variant="primary" block>Add</b-btn>
            </div>
        </b-card>
    </b-card-group>

    <div class="card-pagination">
        <div class="page-index" v-for="i in nbPages" :key="i"  @click="goto(i)" :class={active:currentPage(i)}></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      clubs: [
          {id:1, description:'chelsea is the best club in the world and chelsea has a great player', price:1000, country:'england'},
          {id:2, description:'liverpool has salah', price:900, country:'england'},
          {id:3, description:'mu fans', price:800, country:'england'},
          {id:4, description:'city has a great coach. Thas is guardiola', price:700, country:'england'},
          {id:5, description:'arsenal player', price:600, country:'england'},
          {id:6, description:'tottenham in london', price:500, country:'england'},
          {id:7, description:'juventus stadium', price:400, country:'italy'},
          {id:8, description:'madrid sell ronaldo', price:300, country:'spain'},
          {id:9, description:'barcelona in the spain', price:200, country:'spain'},
          {id:10, description:'psg buys neymar at a fantastic price', price:100, country:'france'}
      ],
      paginatedClubs:[],
      nbPages:0,
      nbRowPerPage:4,
      currentPageIndex:0
    }
  },
  computed: {
      formattedClubs() {
          return this.clubs.reduce((c, n, i) => {
              if (i % 4 === 0) c.push([]);
              c[c.length - 1].push(n);
              return c;
          }, []);
      },
      currentPageClubs(){
         this.createPages();

        return this.paginatedClubs[this.currentPageIndex];
      }
  },
  methods:{
    currentPage(i){
        return i-1===this.currentPageIndex;
    },
      createPages() {

      let lengthAll = Object.keys(this.clubs).length;
      this.nbPages = 0;
       for (let i = 0; i < lengthAll; i = i + this.nbRowPerPage) {
        this.paginatedClubs[this.nbPages] = this.clubs.slice(
          i,
          i + this.nbRowPerPage
        );
        this.nbPages++;
      }
    },
    goto(i){

      this.currentPageIndex=i-1;
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
.card-pagination{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding:20px;
}
.page-index{
  margin-left:10px;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border-radius:15px;
  background:#007bff
}
.active{
   width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Why don't you use carousel like this : https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/carousel ? Because it doesn't show a slide. It seems normal pagination. No slider. I want to use `<b-carousel...`

Answer (score 1):

`<b-carousel>` supports only showing a single slide at a time. You can, however, place cards inside the slide.  You could place 1, 2 or more cards per slide.